# Visual Studio Console-Like Blinking Cursor?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Is there any way to make a cursor look something like the blinking, square cursor used in console applications, say, inside of a text box instead of the regular vertical line? Example:
https://gyazo.com/db9f5661d493c32e48434eed2fa45252

Answer (score 0):

You can control the caret (cursor) using the [Win API Caret Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468799%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

A simple custom WinForm TextBox can be given a blinking caret like this:

```
Public Class MyTB : Inherits TextBox
   <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
   Private Shared Function CreateCaret(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal hBitmap As IntPtr, ByVal nWidth As Integer, ByVal nHeight As Integer) As Boolean
   End Function

   <DllImport("user32.dll")>
   Private Shared Function DestroyCaret() As Boolean
   End Function

   <DllImport("user32.dll")>
   Private Shared Function SetCaretBlinkTime(ByVal uMSeconds As UInt32) As Boolean
   End Function

   <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
   Private Shared Function ShowCaret(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr) As Boolean
   End Function

   Protected Overrides Sub OnGotFocus(e As EventArgs)
      MyBase.OnGotFocus(e)
      MyTB.CreateCaret(Me.Handle, Nothing, 5, Me.Font.Height)
      MyTB.SetCaretBlinkTime(500UI)
      MyTB.ShowCaret(Me.Handle)
   End Sub

   Protected Overrides Sub OnLostFocus(e As EventArgs)
      MyBase.OnLostFocus(e)
      MyTB.DestroyCaret()
   End Sub
End Class
```